# Combobox Python PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, pyqt5, multiple-columns

I have the following code:

#Create ComboBox

```
combo = QComboBox(self)
combo.addItem("Apple")
combo.addItem("Amazon")
combo.activated.connect(self.comboChoice)
navbar.addWidget(combo)
```

This combobox will list 'Apple' and 'Amazon' in the list.

I want to have two columns. The first column is company name, and the second column is the website. The second column shall be hidden. When I click the company name, the action should pop up a message with the company website. For example:

Apple | [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) (hidden) > click on Apple, the message pop up shall display 'www.apple.com'.

Thanking all your input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you could use a simple list of values and recall them according to the activated combobox index.

Nonetheless, QComboBox offers a more dynamic solution, and you don't need a "second column", as you can use custom [user data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem) when adding individual items:

```
    self.combo = QComboBox(self)
    self.combo.addItem("Apple", "www.apple.com")
    self.combo.addItem("Amazon", "www.amazon.com")
    self.combo.activated.connect(self.comboChoice)

def comboChoice(self, index):
    print(self.combo.itemData(index))
```

Comment: I am getting
```
NameError: name 'combo' is not defined
```

Comment: @MahaPappan That completely depends on your code: please note that I've set the combo as instance attribute (`self.combo = `, opposite to your `combo = `, so you should access the combo in the same way I did. Please check your code and try to understand what happens. Also do some research about classes, instances and their attributes, that's basic knowledge of python (and programming in general) that you cannot ignore.

Comment: I got that working. Yes, parent (classes) and child (instances) relationship makes lot of sense. Thank you for the share and most appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, and remember that if an answer solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray checkmark on its left.